# Django-oscar installation as new project with oscar files on project directory

Tags: python, django, django-oscar

I would like to start a new Project in Django. I want to use some django-oscar apps from Github.

Django-oscar already providing a [pip infall django-oscar] command to install it. But this time osacar files goes to site-package directory. I want them in my current project directory. Is there any solution.

Comment: Honestly, you probably don't want Oscar in your project directory--it has a ton of apps! Plus, you can override any particular app or model by following the "Customisation" instructions. I keep Oscar github open in one window to reference while coding in another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clone the github project, and then run `make sandbox`, it will install the requirements but it won't install/copy the oscar app to the `site-packages` folder. It will use it from where it is.

Its best to create a new [virtual env](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/virtualenv.html#usage) for this, then create a folder where you want the oscar clone to be.
Then run the following commands

```
git clone https://github.com/tangentlabs/django-oscar.git
make sandbox
python sites/sandbox/manage.py runserver
```

**NB**: If you're on windows, consider using vagrant (or manually setting up a linux vm) because at least one of oscar's requirements ([sh](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sh)) is not available on windows. There's an alternative but its years old. That plus you'll generally have an easier with oscar time not using windows.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. If I need to create a project named <mystrore> how can I create it from the local git source. I am using a MacBook Pro and I don't have any issue vita Unix commands.

If I create a new virtualenv and create a new django project named store. Then is it possible to add the osacr-apps by copy-paste it in my project directory.

Comment: Sure you can. You can start with either the demo or the sandbox app and build upon them. Or you can check Oscar's docs, there's a page on how to build a store from scratch.

Comment: Yes it is possible. thanks for the information. here are the steps I followed


1. virtualenv store
2. pip install django==1.6
3. Install required lib like pillow...
4. download django-oscar git source
5. copy the oscar folder from django-oscar folder and paste it inside store project
6. modify settings.py and urls.py